# $A$ be $n×n$ matrix $A^{n}=0$ ,$A^{n-1}$ not equal to zero a vector $v$ belongs to R^n.then how to proof {V,AV,...A^(n-1)V} is a basis.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, nilpotence

Given $A$ be $n×n$ matrix such that $A^{n}=0$, but $A^{n-1}$ not equal to zero a vector $v$ belongs to $\Bbb{R}^{n}$. Proof that {$V,AV,\cdots,A^{(n-1)}V$}  is a basis.

Comment: Hint: show the vectors are linearly independent by applying $A$ to a linear relation. You're missing the hypothesis that $A^{n-1} v \not= 0$. And you want $v$, not $V$ in the set of vectors.

Comment: Sir here is a problem to show linearly independent. ..let c0v+c1Av....cn-1A^n-1v=0.now multiplying both side with A^n-1 then we get c0A^n-1v=0 .here either c0=0 or A^n-1v=0..so what can i then.??

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is enough prove that $\{v,Av,...,A^{n-1}v\}$ is LI. If $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ is such that $$a_{1}v+...+a_{n}A^{n-1}v=0 ,$$
applying $A^{n-1}$ in this equation, we have $$a_{1}A^{n-1}v=0 ,$$
so $a_{1}=0$. Similarly one can prove that $a_{2}=...=a_{n}=0$.

Comment: But A^(n-1)v may be zero what about this please answer. ...

Comment: By hypothesis $A^{n-1}v\neq 0$.

Comment: What is hypothesis? ?

Comment: $A$ matrix such that $A^{n}=0$ and $A^{n-1}\neq 0$ (i.e., there is $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $A^{n-1}v\neq 0)$.

I take this $v$.

Comment: Not clear!!!with this cause. .

Comment: Suppose that $A^{n}=0$ and $A^{n-1}v\neq 0$. Applying $A^{n-1}$ in $$a_{1}v+...+a_{n}A^{n-1}v=0$$ we have $$a_{1}A^{n-1}+a_{2}A^{n}v+a_{3}A^{n+1}+...+a_{n}A^{2n-1}v=0.$$ Note that $A^{n}v=A^{n+1}v=...=A^{2n-1}v=0$ (by hypohtesis). Thus $a_{1}A^{n-1}+a_{2}A^{n}v+a_{3}A^{n+1}+...+a_{n}A^{2n-1}v=a_{1}A^{n-1}=0$. Since, by hypothesis, $A^{n-1}v\neq 0$, we have $a_{1}=0$.

Repeating this process we conclude that $a_{i}=0$.